# NodeJS Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for ideas/help to improve my code. It's already working, but I am not confident with it and not really proud of it. This is short version of my function -

```
module.exports.serverlist = async () => {
let promises = [];
const serverlist = [];
serverlist.push({ mon_sid: 'AAA', mon_hostname: 'aaaa.com', mon_port: 80 })
serverlist.push({ mon_sid: 'BBB', mon_hostname: 'bbbb.com', mon_port: 80 })

serverlist.forEach(async (Server) => {
    if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_DB')) {
        // Function home.checkOracleDatabase return promise, same as above functions
        promises.push(home.checkOracleDatabase(Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port));
    } else if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_HDB')) {
        promises.push(home.checkHANADatabase(Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port));
    } else {
        promises.push(home.checkPort(Server.mon_port, Server.mon_hostname, 1000));
    }
})

for (let i = 0; i < serverlist.length; i++) {
    serverlist[i].status = await promises[i];
}

console.table(serverlist);
```

What does the code do?: 
- It asynchronously performing needed availability check of the service.

What is the expectation? 
- That the code will run asynchronously, at the end of function it will wait for all promises to be resolved, for failed results it will perform the check over again, and to have more control over the promises. At this moment the promises are not really connected somehow with the array of systems, it just base on the order but it can be problematic in future.

If someone can assist/give some advises, I would be more than happy.
Also I am not sure how many parallel asynchronous operations NodeJS can perform (or the OS). Currently there are 30 systems on the list, but in future it can be 200-300, I am not sure if it can be handled at once.

### Update

I used promise.all - it works fine. However the problem is as I mentioned, I don't have any control over the $promises array. The results as saved in the sequence as they were triggered, and this is how they are being assigned back to serverlist[i].status array from $promises. But I would like to have more control over it, I want to have some index, or something in the $promises array so I can make sure that the results are assigned to PROPER systems (not luckily counting that by the sequence it will be assigned as it should).

Also I would like to extend this function with option to reAttempt failed checks, and for that definitely I need some index in $promises array.

### Update 2

After all of your suggestion this is how the code looks for now -

```
function performChecks(serverlist) {
    const Checks = serverlist.map(Server => {
        if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_DB')) {
            let DB_SID = Server.mon_sid.replace('_DB', '');
            return home.checkOracleDatabase(DB_SID, Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port)
        } else if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_HDB')) {
            let DB_SID = Server.mon_sid.replace('_HDB', '');
            return home.checkHANADatabase(DB_SID, Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port);
        } else {
            return home.checkPort(Server.mon_port, Server.mon_hostname, 1000)
        }
    })

    return Promise.allSettled(Checks)
}

// Ignore the way that the function is created, it's just for debug purpose
(async function () {
    let checkResults = [];
    let reAttempt = [];
    let reAttemptResults = [];
    const serverlist = [];

serverlist.push({ mon_id: 1, mon_sid: 'AAA', mon_hostname: 'hostname_1', mon_port: 3203 })
serverlist.push({ mon_id: 2, mon_sid: 'BBB', mon_hostname: 'hostname_2', mon_port: 3201 })
serverlist.push({ mon_id: 3, mon_sid: 'CCC', mon_hostname: 'hostname_3', mon_port: 3203 })

    // Perform first check for all servers
    checkResults = await performChecks(serverlist);

    // Combine results from check into serverlist array under status key
    for(let i = 0; i < serverlist.length; i++) {
        serverlist[i]['status'] = checkResults[i].value;
    }

    // Check for failed results and save them under reAttempt variable
    reAttempt = serverlist.filter(Server => Server.status == false);

    // Perform checks again for failed results to make sure that it wasn't temporary netowrk/script issue/lag
    // Additionally performChecks function will accept one more argument in future which will activate additional trace for reAttempt
    reAttemptResults = await performChecks(reAttempt);

    // Combine results from reAttempt checks into reAttempt array
    for(let i = 0; i < reAttempt.length; i++) {
        reAttempt[i]['status'] = reAttemptResults[i].value;
    }

    // Combine reAttempt array with serverlist array so serverlist can have latest updated data
    serverlist.map(x => Object.assign(x, reAttempt.find(y => y.mon_id == x.mon_id)));

    // View the results
    console.table(serverlist);

})();
```

Comment: if your code is working codereview may be a better place for your question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're going to want to use `Promise.allSettled(promises)` or at least `Promise.all(promises)` rather than that for loop at the end.

Comment: Wow thanks guys for so quick response! All of you, really appreciate, i already have headache with the code. I'll review all of your answers first. Also I'll edit my first post with more missing code, sorry for it, wanted you guys to avoid getting headache with all the mess code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly instead of doing a for each and push promises you can map them and do a Promise all. You need no push. Your function can return directly your promise all call. The caller can await it or use then...
Something like this (I didn't test it)

```js
// serverlist declaration
function getList(serverlist) {
const operations = serverlist.map(Server => {
    if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_DB')) {
        return home.checkOracleDatabase(Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port);
    } else if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_HDB')) {
        return home.checkHANADatabase(Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port);
    } else {
        return home.checkPort(Server.mon_port, Server.mon_hostname, 1000);
    }
});

return Promise.all(operations)
}

const serverlist = [...]
const test = await getList(serverlist)

// test is an array of fulfilled/unfulfilled results of Promise.all
```

So I would create a function that takes a list of operations(serverList) and returns the promise all like the example above without awaiting for it.
The caller would await it or using another promise all of a series of other calls to your function.
Potentially you can go deeper like Inception :)

```js
// on the caller you can go even deeper

await Promise.all([getList([...]) , getList([...]) , getList([...]) ])
```

Considering what you added you can return something more customized like:

```js
    if (Server.mon_sid.includes('_DB')) {
        return home.checkOracleDatabase(Server.mon_hostname, Server.mon_port).then(result => ({result, name: 'Oracle', index:..., date:..., hostname: Server.mon_hostname, port: Server.mon_port}))
```

In the case above your promise would return a json with the output of your operation as result, plus few additional fields you might want to reuse to organize your data.

Comment: Checking it right away, I already tried promise.all but the problem is as I updated in the main post, I had no control over the $promises results. it worked fine, but I never can be sure that the results are assigned to proper system in serverlist array actually.

Comment: What do you mean with I don't have control of $promise? A promise.all returns an array of results in the same order as you give. You can find fulfilled promises or rejected ones when you await them (or use then). The rejected ones can be handled in other ways, you can either retry. If your lists of servers are async you need another layer on top of the function I wrote. But to be more precise I need an example of what you mean with no control.
If you need more details you can simply return more data with your promise, some metadata you might reuse it to identify them (including problems).

Comment: I'll try to explain what exactly I mean with lack of control over the $promise array. At this moment trying to understand the idea that you gave me above. But I have problems with it, I am not really sure if I understand how it suppose to work. This is what I tried so far, but it doesn't give any results so far. https://i.imgur.com/nK5TDrG.png

Comment: // Edit seems I did a mistake, missed () on the end of (async function () {.. // Will update in second how it worked.

Comment: Jac, seems like it worked.
https://i.imgur.com/jSrITuG.png

But how should I now call the whole array? I can run it for particular serverlist[index] but if I want to run it for whole array? 

What I would want to achieve is,
execute checks for whole array serverlist[i], and save the results in serverlist[i].status
And also I want to make sure that all of the statuses are resolved.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think we reached same point as with my code, as all the time problem is that I need to run the whole array at once (all servers check should run at once), asynchronously. After all checks are scheduled to run, then I need to wait for all of them to be completed, and then operate on the results.

Comment: Any ideas @Jac?

Comment: If you await or "then" the Promise.all you will execute all the async operations and wait for them to finish. Then you have an array with the results. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: If you need to do a list of operations in async you can create an array of promises and await for its Promise.all call. Only when everything is finished the Promise.all would return an array of fulfilled/unfulfilled results in the same order as you give when you called it. Pay attention not to do too many requests at once, it might be overkill. I would suggest you to divide your array in blocks, let's say 10 operations and execute those async in blocks. I didn't get very well what your concerns are, can you write a pseudo code example?

Comment: Taking a look at your screenshot, you made a mistake in the promise.all, this is probably what you meant. It should be only:

const test = await getList(serverlist)

You added an additional Promise.all... I did put it in my answer to say that you can make something deeper if you want but that was not strictly needed if you want to execute one single set of operations. Let me change my answer...

Comment: Wow, your last response make it working like a charm, I am still checking if it's running fully asynchronous, but so far it looks great. It's starting all the checks at once and waiting for their completion. I am doing some tests, and will come back to confirm!. :)

Comment: Thank you dude! Seems it's working as I expected.
https://i.imgur.com/YlKxSQB.png

Execution time for the checks are quite identical to my code, but at least code looks way better I guess.

Now I need to find best performance way to assign results to serverlist array as serverlist.status key. I've used loop before for that, and you guys said it's poor result and suggested to use map. I'll come back asap with results if everything works as expected

Comment: Apart from that I also need to check for a best way to re-check failed attempts.
Not sure if it will be better to do it by -

- Perform all checks
- Assign results to serverlist[].status
- Check for failed statuses in serverlist[].status
- Perform checks again for failed statuses and assign final results to serverlist[].status

OR

- Perform all checks
- Check for failed results
- Perform checks again for failed statuses
- Assign final results to serverlist[].status

Comment: Your question seems to be never ending :)

Comment: Thank you Jac for help, and sorry for all of those newbie questions. Coding is not my primary role, doing it as hobby in my free time after work and hard to find time to gain more experience. 

I've updated my first post with the latest version of that what I managed to create.
Can you take a look and if something suggest some corrections or just say if again the code is trash? I've explained each step what I wanted it to do. At this moment it works as I wanted it, but if its best practice - hard to say.

Comment: You might want to use allSettled instead of all. Using that you will not stop at the first promise rejection but you will wait for every one in case of errors too. See this page =>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Node >= 12.9 is needed

Comment: Added, at this moment didn't felt any difference between Promise.all and Promise.allSettled but prolly I would feel it in production run. Updated the first post also. Apart from that, something else looks really bad there?

Comment: The differences between those 2 approaches is when you have rejections, "all" stops at the first rejection and returns that to you, "allSettled" does wait for all of them to finish and gives you an array of statuses and results (see the link I gave you before) so you can see which ones you might have to execute again and the ones were ok (in case)

Comment: Ok, thank you Jac. Will check for it deeper to also consider statuses from the promise for the re-attempt. Again, thank you so much for assistance. I think I can now move forward a little with the code. I've marked your answer as resolver answer, hope it will help someone else in future also. Wish you all the best! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For more consistency and for resolving this question i/we(other people which can help you) need *all* code this all variables definition (because for now i can't find where is the `promises` variable is defined). Thanks